# Add data from activity to email message body

Tags: android, string, email

I feel dumb for having to ask this but I cannot find how to take UI information from multiple EditText views and place in an email body. FYI I have the intent down, I just want to populate the message body.

```
    Intent buildingfireemail = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            buildingfireemail.setType("plain/text");///.setType("message/rfc822")
            buildingfireemail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"to@email.com"});
            buildingfireemail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            buildingfireemail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text"
    //////////////I need to add data from 80+ views into here.
    );try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(buildingfireemail, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(BuildingFireActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: Im new to this and learning as i go FYI.

Comment: It seems that your code is correct. What you are getting with this code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function which returns the whole String from all your text edits. For example:

```
private String getText() {
    String text = "";

    text += mEditText1.getText().toString() + "\n";
    text += mEditText2.getText().toString() + "\n";

    return text;
}
```

Use like:

```
buildingfireemail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getText());
```

Init member variables for class:

```
private EditText mEditText1;
```

Take all edit texts to member variables in onCreate after setContentView:

```
mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.layout.editText1);
```

Comment: I meant im really new . . . i am not sure where that goes or which parts i replace with what i have for titles?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , editText.getText().toString());
try 
{
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```